# Computed property with matchMedia function Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, media-queries, matchmedia

I have some problem with the matchMedia function that I wrote inside my computed property in Vue. The problem is when I load/refresh page, the function does not work.
It only back to work after I resize the screen in Responsive Design Mode at the browser.

Here the code of my app.js

```
     computed: {
        widthChange() {
            if (matchMedia) {
                    var mqT = window.matchMedia(" (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 600px) ")

                    function changeWidthT(mqT) {
                    const sectionRight = document.querySelector(".section-right")
                    if (mqT.matches) {
                        sectionRight.classList.remove("col-7")
                    }
                    else {
                        sectionRight.classList.add("col-7")
                    }
                }

                mqT.addListener(changeWidthT)
            }
        }
    },
```

and I call the computed property inside the parent of the page

```
<div class="frontpage-parent" :class="widthChange">...
</div>
```

Comment: How is matchmedia defined? If it comes from another script, there are quite a chances it is not defined at the time Vue compute the value for the first time. Since Vue caches the results of `computed` properties, it will not be revaluated until one of the observables changes.

Comment: Actually after reading a bit more of what you did here - this code should not live in the computed properties at all. You don't even return anything!

Comment: Oh, this is standard window element. Neat, good to know!

Comment: I placed the function in the component with Vue.extend. I tried to use methods property but still gave me the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling widthChange() in the mounted hook so that it runs on load?

**Edit**
Try placing `const tst = this.widthChange;` in the mousnted hook

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I just dont know how to call the the function inside the mounted hook

Comment: @αякjυηισяK ah ya, its a computed property. Try this, make it return something and just place const tst = widthChange; in the mounted hook. Or even maybe just place widthChange;

Comment: thank you, but the mounted hook gave me an error saying that the function is not defined

Comment: Yes, dont call it as a function. Just treat it like a variable

Comment: If you read here you'll see that you define them like functions but you access them like variables. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: I'm really sorry, since I'm just a newbie I still dont know how to call it as variable. I'm sorry

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have edited my answer. Check the new edit.

Comment: @αякjυηισяK Ok, I understand. I have edited my answer. Check the new edit.

Comment: it give error saying "ReferenceError: widthChange is not defined".

Comment: @αякjυηισяK ah yes, sorry, I always do this mistake, its this.widthChange; you need to put the this

Comment: you save me.... I've been stuck in this problem for 2 days and finally TT

Comment: @αякjυηισяK you are welcome. Now that it works and you have figured out what the problem was, you might want to consider BroiSatse answer in that you are missusing computed properties. The convention is that they are like at varials that are determined automatically or something like that and not to do work in. But since its Javascript it will work anyway

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `computed` properties here. They are supposed to be getters, meaning they are only to return ready to sue values. You're actually attaching event listeners there.

Instead, you need to use data attribute and initialize your listeners within mounted hook:

```
export default {
  name: 'Blah',
  data () {
    const tabletViewQuery = matchMedia('...')
    return {
      tabletViewQuery: tabletViewQuery.
      tabletView: tableViewQuery.matches,
    }  
  },
  mounted () {
     this.tabletViewQuery.addListener(() => {
       this.tabletView = tableViewQuery.matches
     }
  }
}
```

and use it in a table:

```
<div class="section-right" :class="{ 'col-7': tabletView }">
```

However, probably much cleaner solution would be to use [vue-match-media](https://github.com/drenglish/vue-match-media) plugin.

Comment: thank you for the answer, you great can define something that I never thought before.

Answer (score 0):

### `matchMedia` in Vue with reactiveness

The aforementioned answers did not work for me. Improved BroiSatse's answer by replacing the deprecated `addListener` with `change` event as mentioned on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList

Vue Options API with Typescript example:

```
data(): { mediaQuery: MediaQueryList; isTablet: boolean; } {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)');

    return {
        mediaQuery,
        isTablet: mediaQuery.matches
    };
},
mounted(): void {
    this.mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', () => {
        this.isTablet = this.mediaQuery.matches;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A year later, but with a small tweak I made it work in Vuejs for a mobile/desktop purposes:

```
computed: {
...
...
      widthChange() {
        if (matchMedia) {
          const matchMediaQuery = window.matchMedia(" (max-width: 1024px) ")
          const changeWidthT = (matchMediaQuery) => {
            this.isMobileExperience = matchMediaQuery.matches ? true : false;
          }
          mqT.addListener(changeWidthT)
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() { 
      const awakeResizeListener = this.widthChange;
    },
...
...
```

With a `v-if` and `v-else` evaluating a `isMobileExperience` data option you are good to go with the resizing.

Hope this can help anyone